# App for sending large HTTPWebRequest is crashing with outofmemory exception

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

The requirement was to create an application for stress testing of a web service.
Idea was to bombard, say, 1000K HTTPWebRequests of size 4 KB to the web service
In order to achieve this, we have created an app whose structure is something like few threads are adding data to be sent in a queue and a thread pool is sending those requests asynchronously.
`Task responseTask = Task.Factory.FromAsync(testRequest.BeginGetResponse, testRequest.EndGetResponse, null);"` But now what is happening is after some amount of time the no of requests/sec are getting decreased significantly (may be because the response time of service has increased.. but again if we are sending the requests asynchronously, will the response time matter?). And in addition to that, after some time the tool crashses with the message "application has stopped working" and exception is shown as outofmemory exception.

One thing I have observed is just before app crash, the response time of the web service increases significantly. Is it the indirect reason of the crash?

What is the remedy for it?

Comment: I would assume that the slow down is caused by the GC trying to keep up.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are queueing up tasks without throttling so the amount of pending requests increases infinitely. You need to throttle, even when using async behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Earlier I also thought that this could be the reason. However I have restricted the en queuing by restricting the private bytes of the process to 500 MB. I know this is much higher limit though. 
Also I have observed that after restricting, the processor utilization by the app was increased significantly. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: Ok, when you restrict the memory of your process (how are you doing that?) you are causing OOM-errors of course. After all, you deny yourself memory. The app gets slower because the GC is frantically trying to free up bytes because it has no room left to expand. Your process is being slowed by lots of G2 collections.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process currentProcess = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess();
long privateSetSizeInBytes = currentProcess.PrivateMemorySize64;

long privateSetSizeInMBytes=privateSetSizeInBytes/1024/1024;
if (privateSetSizeInMBytes < 500)
{//add requests
}

This is the code for restricting the size in memory..

Comment: Hm, my explanation is not valid for this case (I was assuming you used Windows job objects). My next guess is that using and freeing lots of buffers causes memory fragmentation. Socket IO is pinning the byte[] used in the IO. Try consolidating all buffers into one or few big array (16mb in size or so).

Comment: dint get you properly.. What you mean by consolidating all buffers into one or few big arrays?